# Problem with laser sensor and heigthmap

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi!
I'm working in a simulation that includes a laser sensor (the Hokuyo model) and a heigthmap. I have found a problem , and in some places of my heigthmaps, it seems that the laser is going through the model. In this picture you can see the effect:

[image: image description]

Has anyone have a similar problem?Any idea how this can be solve? I use Gazebo 7 in Ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20267/problem-with-laser-sensor-and-heigthmap/) by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 68 on 2018-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is a known bug. I've had a similar problem with objects falling through the heightmap. See here: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18088/gazebo-8-heightmap-objects-clipping-through-collision/

And here's the bitbucket issue: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/245/heightmap-visual-is-offset-from-collision

Until this issue is solved, you'll have to come up with a workaround. One possible way would be to create a 3D model (in Blender for example) of your terrain and insert that into your world. However, that would probably be very tedious and I haven't actually tested if the collision of 3D models is accurate.

---

Originally posted by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) with karma: 376 on 2018-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) on 2018-08-21**:
Thanks!

I actually was able to create the heigthmap as a model in blender  following this tutorial http://stevemarti.com/from-2d-to-3d-turning-images-into-objects/ and I think the problem is solved. Now I have to find a way to make this new heightmap fixed (like the one that Gazebo creates) so i don't accidentally move it when I try to place and move things on top of it.

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) on 2018-08-21**:
As Raskkii says, default Gazebo height map isn't great. Look at the default empty .world's ground plane model. That should be a good reference as to how to configure your custom heightmap.

link: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/models/ground_plane/model.sdf

You'll want to set the model's static flag to true: http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=model#model_static